# Execute eval on dynamic expression

Tags: node.js, eval, puppeteer

I have a dictionary that is params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"]. It has different expressions that need to be executed. I am trying to execute like this:

```
if("browser.evaluateJs" in params["actions"]){

            for (let key of Object.keys(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"])) {
                console.log(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]);
                ctx[key] = eval(await params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]);
                console.log(ctx[key]);
              }
        }
```

expression contained in that dictionary is page.waitForXPath('//div[@class='price-text']'). I am trying to scrape a website using pupeteer. And need to get this xpath. But it is giving this error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

How do I fix it?

Edit:
I have used page.evaluate like this:

```
if("browser.evaluateJs" in params["actions"]){

            for (let key of Object.keys(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"])) {
                console.log(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]);
                ctx[key] = page.evaluate(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]);
                console.log(ctx[key]);
              }
        }
```

and params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]  contains e`lement => {return element.textContent;}, (await page.$x('//div[@class='price-text']'))[0]`
but this gives Promise {  }. How do I fix it?

Edit 2:

I put await like this:

```
ctx[key] = await page.evaluate(params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]);
```

and it is throwing this error:

```
 Error: Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Edit3:
Since Im reading it from yml file so I have put it like this:
mykey : "element => {return element.textContent;}, (await page.$x('//div[@class=\"price-text\"]'))[0]"

The error still persists

Comment: [vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) is available in node, eval is still evil

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what about page.evaluate?

Comment: put `await` in front

Comment: tried that. it gives an error too

Comment: @LawrenceCherone added the error

Comment: check the syntax of whats in `params["actions"]["browser.evaluateJs"][key]` as `page.$x('//div[@class='price-text']')` is invalid.. also if its a function just execute it, there is no need for eval

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it doesn't get executed directly. Plus it is correct syntax. I tried it separately

Comment: `'//div[@class='price-text']'` is not correct, quotes!

Comment: Yes, you need different quotes: `page.$x('//div[@class="price-text"]')`

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt it is still giving an error